# How can I know when a flag is accepted or denied?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm playing with the Foursquare API and I was wondering if there are any way to know when a flag is accepted or denied.

The [documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/flag) doesn't says anything about what is the content of the response when I flag a venue. The `Response fields` is empty..

When flagging, the response look like that:

```
{
    "meta": {...},
    "notifications": [...],
    "response": {
        "id": "4b82fd8ef964a52049f130e3",
        "name": "times square",
        "contact": {},
        "location": {
            "lat": 43.642197,
            "lng": 6.979622,
            "cc": "FR",
            "city": "New york",
            "state": "New york",
            "country": "France"
        },
        "canonicalUrl": "https://foursquare.com/v/times-square-new-york/4b82fd8ef964a52049f130e3",
        "canonicalPath": "/v/times-square-new-york/4b82fd8ef964a52049f130e3",
        "categories": [],
        "verified": false,
        "stats": {...},
        "creator": {...},
        "flags": {
            "count": 1,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "5272152d11d25a4be68777a1",
                    "type": "remove",
                    "comments": [],
                    "reporters": [
                        {...}
                    ],
                    "resolvedTime": "Thu Oct 31 09:20:17 UTC 2013",
                    "resolvedUsers": [],
                    "value": {
                        "reason": "doesnt_exist"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to re-call the same query (as when I'm flagging a venue) and the response will content something to tell the flag is either *accepted* or *denied*? Like in `resolvedUsers`?

**Update:**

It seems that I can call this url to get a list of all flag for a given venue. Then I can check if my flag id is present, otherwise it means the flag has been handled. BUT I don't know it the flag was accepted or denied...

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b23dd27f964a5207c5b24e3/flags?v=20120321&locale=en
```

And by the way, `/flags` return the new venue in case of duplicate is accepted, not the duplicate. Makes it harder to determine ..

Answer (score 1):

The flag will go through and be put into the queues for our superusers to moderate, there's no "accepting" or "denying" of a flag—the request of the flag may eventually get accepted or denied though. There's no way to see if a particular flag was accepted or denied through the API, but you'll know if it was accepted if the venue eventually gets changed.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of.. I have to *guess* if the flag has been handled. I imagine this is what guys behind 4sweep have done to handle their flag system (with response, and even alternative resolution, etc ..), right?